# Forbidden Access. CGI -apache

Tags: apache-2.4, cgi

I am trying to run a cgi script using apache but when I input in the browser https://localhost/cgi-bin/(anything) it says "You don't have permission to access /cgi-bin/(anything) on this server. 
I have added

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

And have also to my knowledge put the right permissions on the files. Is there anything else missing?

Comment: Try `+FollowSymLinks` instead of `+SymLinksIfOwnerMatch`

Comment: @Froggiz It still seems to not work.

Comment: What does it say in the Apache error log when you try this?

Comment: @PaulHaldane I cant find my error log files. I think it may be due to the fact that when i netstat -a I cannot see the server being run. Is there a guide somewhere to help me through the setup?

Comment: Is files owner www-data or some other user? You can find with "ls -l" command. Also check "systemctl status apache2"

Comment: @mandza its ok mate I figured it out 6 years ago

Comment: But you're not going to tell us how you you verified the permissions nor how you resolved the issue?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because user resolved issue but did not disclose how.

Answer (score 0):

You can find information on the official web site:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html